# Admob isn't refreshing ad's

Tags: android, admob

Since a few days my ads from admob aren't refreshing anymore , is this a global problem?
Everything was working fine and I didn't change a thing.

```
05-10 19:00:15.594: I/Ads(824): onReceiveAd()
05-10 19:00:28.705: I/Ads(824): Refreshing ad.
05-10 19:00:29.345: I/Ads(824): adRequestUrlHtml: <html><head><script 
....
```

Logcat shows that it should refresh but the same ad remains.

Comment: Perhaps your not getting enough impressions to request ads. Whats your fill rate?

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide some code?  If you are doing one of the following:

1. Requesting ads in xml and using `ads:testDevices`
2. Requesting ads in code and using `adRequest.addTestDevice()`

Then you are probably in test mode, and you are getting the same test ad.